# In PostgreSQL, get a minimum value if there is none

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry if the title did not match the actual question. I'm not sure how to phrase this.

In Postgres, I have users that can be at a station. The stations are numbered 1 to 5. I have a table `users` and it has a column `station`. If a user is at a station, `station` value is the number of the station, if not, it is NULL. Here's how I find the number of users at each station:

```
SELECT station, count(users) AS users
    FROM users
    WHERE station IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY station ORDER BY station;
```

This yields:

```
 station | users 
---------+---------
       1 |     4
       2 |     1
       3 |     1
```

But that's not *really* true. There are zero users on station 4 and 5. How can I address that? I would like to use this query as a view to calculate other things, but I need all the stations there. I don't need a table for the stations, as far as I know: I'm not going to use them anywhere else.

So how do I account for the unused stations? Do I really need to make a table for them and reference the stations table from the users table or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have a table `stations`, you can handle this with a `left join`:

```
SELECT s.station, count(u.station) AS users
FROM stations s LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON s.station = u.station
GROUP BY s.station
ORDER BY s.station;
```

Without such a table, you can use `generate_series()`:

```
SELECT s.station, count(u.station) AS users
FROM generate_series(1, 5) as s(station) LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON s.station = u.station
GROUP BY s.station
ORDER BY s.station;
```

Comment: You should `COUNT(u.station)` instead of `count(users)` (in the first query)

Comment: @zerkms . . . I agree.  In fact, I'm guessing the `users.users` isn't really a field, so the OP has a typo in the original question.  (S/he claims that `count(u.users)` produces valid output.)

Comment: Yep, I also rely on the fact that OP's query is correct (even though it does look weird) :-)

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about `generate_series()`. But I suppose it's what I needed!